# unable to build binutils on macosx

Tags: ld, macos-sierra, binutils, mach-o, dwarf

I need to build ld from sources on OSX 10.12.3 (16D32). I cloned the last version from git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git and tried to build it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-werror (there are a lot of warnings, so I disable them)

make
```

but I got

```
 In file included from dwarf2read.c:72:
 ./common/gdb_unlinker.h:35:35: error: '__nonnull__' attribute 
 is invalid for the implicit this argument
  unlinker (const char *filename) ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL (1)
```

Have anybody seen it and know how to fix it? 
I need only ld to check why it shows

```
ld: warning: can't parse dwarf compilation unit info in
```

on OSX, when Ubuntu works fine and objdump doesn't show any elf symbols.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. The linker that's part of the Apple development tools is Apple's own `ld64`, not `ld` from GNU binutils. You can see the error message you reference in [Apple's source for `ld64`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-274.2/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp.auto.html) (within `Parser<A>::parseDebugInfo`).

Comment: Got it. You are right, I was confused by ld name. ld -v shows that it is ld64 that can be build.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build wrong ld. 
ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-274.2
shows that I had to build ld64 from apple sources.
Thanks bdash for pointing that.